Why is the texture still not showing on the screen after addActor in Libgdx?
I'm trying to create a Match-3 game, I've created a Tile class to represent individual game tiles, which holds both the image and data about the tile's row and column positions. Additionally, I have a Board class that contains an array of Tile objects, specifically an 8x8 grid. This is the core structure for the game grid. In the GameScreen class, I attempt to add each Tile as an actor, which should display them on the screen.
However, the setup is not functioning as expected. The game fails to render the tiles correctly, and I'm unsure whether the issue lies in how the actors are being added, or if the problem is related to other aspects of rendering or game logic. The next step is to debug the interaction between Tile and Board, ensuring that the tiles are correctly positioned and rendered on the game stage. Please help me.
Here the code:
public class Tile extends Image
{
    public int row;
    public int col;
    public int type = -1;

    public Tile(int col, int row){
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public void init(TextureRegion sprite, int index)
    {
        setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
        setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(sprite));
        debug();
        this.type = index;
    }

    public void setRowCol(int row, int col){
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
}

public class Board extends Group implements Disposable
{
    Match3Game game;
    Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> entities;
    Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[8][8];
    //
    public Board(Match3Game game, Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> sprites)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.entities = sprites;

        initialize();
    }
    //
    private void initialize()
    {
        setBounds(0,0,640,640);

        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tiles[i].length; j++)
            {
                Tile tile = new Tile(i ,j);
                tile.addListener(clickListener);
                // random number in atlas
                int num = MathUtils.random(1,5);
                tile.init(this.entities.get(num),num);
                tile.setPosition(j * tile.getWidth(), i * tile.getHeight());
                tiles[i][j] = tile;
                //add tile in addActor
                this.addActor(tile);

                if(tiles[i][j] == null)
                    Gdx.app.log("Board", "Could not found Board Texture");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

public class GameScreen extends ParentScreen
{
    Match3Game game;
    Board board;
    //Constructor
    public GameScreen(Match3Game game)
    {
        super(game);
        this.game = game;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        super.show();
        //
        setUpBoard();
    }
    
    private void setUpBoard()
    {
        //todo
        board = new Board(game, Assets.getTexture().findRegions("color"));
            //set position
////        board.setPosition(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/5, Align.center);
////        board.setPosition(0,0);
        board.debugAll();
        this.addActor(board);
    }
    ...
}


Can't see any Camera, Viewscreen and Stage in your GameScreen. If you got some, don't forget to add Board actor to the stage.
I have mine in Main class:
@Override
public void create() {
    guiCamera = new OrthographicCamera(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    guiCamera.setToOrtho(false, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    if (isMobile()) {
        guiViewport = new ExtendViewport(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, guiCamera);
    } else {
        guiViewport = new FitViewport(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, guiCamera);
    }
}

and then, in screen i (I have many screens):
public ScreenLoader(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setViewport(guiViewport);

Here I init and add actors. And don't forget to:
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

